# Windows explorer: jump to folder by dragging (like macos finder)

Tags: windows, mac

I recently switched to windows from mac and I miss one key feature:

On mac os, when you have a "save as" dialogue open (like from a download) and you have another finder tab/window open you can simply drag from there a folder/file to the download saveAs window and the folder location jumps to there. I cannot do that in windows somehow.

Is there a similar feature?

Comment: I wish you luck but I rather think you're going to end up copy/pasting paths. I used to have something [3rd party] that was halfway to the Mac functionality, but that was waaay back in XP days.

Comment: There is a tool called Listary that brings some of the features I like from Default Folder (on the Mac) into Windows.